# exclude folder in project.json

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

in the new asp.net 5 template there's a project.json in which you can exclude certain directories.

```
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "dist",
    ".tmp"
]
```

As you can see, I added a few folders like 'dist' and '.tmp', but they are still included in the solution explorer. There's not much documentation about this. How to exculde files/folders from your project in vs 2015?

Comment: Where is dist located in the folder hierarchy?  Is it directly off the project root folder?

Comment: I agree. this is a big problem. When I search my solution for text, I don't want to search these folder. And worse, source control thinks all these files need to be added. It's not good at all.

Comment: In my case, node_modules is not showing up but bower_components is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the state of asp.net 5 with visual studio 2015 I can only say that they made it much more difficult and inconvenient to work with task runners like gulp or grunt. Since I'm using Web API 2 to manage my data I switched to Visual Studio Code with bower, gulp and browsersync and this has proven a to be LOT easier and faster with much less clutter.

To make a startup template: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

Now you can use any editor and you get a clear separation of front end and back end development. Plus you get to know gulp and bower and the (minimal) command line stuff which VS2015 tries to do for you (and fails to do so many times).

Oh yes: you don't have to exclude folders anymore, since the template has a much more sensible folder structure

Answer (score 16):

The "exclude" property does not hide the folder from visual studio, it will not make the folder "disappear" from the solution explorer.

**The "exclude" property removes the folder from the compilation search path.**  It is an instruction to the compiler (Roslyn) not the IDE.  As a more comprehensive answer "project.json" is intentionally IDE agnostic.  That is why there is both a projecname.xspoj and a project.json which both contain project configuration information.  This is necessary to allow for more robust cross IDE and cross platform development.

You can verify this behavior yourself with a simple excercise.

1. Add a new class file (buildfail.cs) to your existing project (or
   create a new project) in the root project folder.
2. Ensure buildfail.cs has the same namespace as the other source files in the
   project, contains compilation errors, and is in the root directory.
3. You should see build errors in VS.  If you don't manually build.
4. Create a new folder (excludeme) off the project root and move
   buildfail.cs to that folder.  You should still have build errors.
5. Add excludeme to the exclude property in project.json.  The build errors should be removed because builfail.cs is no longer in the build search path.

You may be wondering what is VS using to know to hide the node_packages folder from the Solution Explorer display.  I am unsure and it may not be user configurable but it isn' the exclude property.  Comment out node_packages in project.json and you will get build errors (package restore failure) but the folder will still be hidden from Solution Explorer.  Since this is IDE specific behavior one would assume that maybe it is defined in projectname.xproj but I found no such property so at this time it would appear to be black box magic by VS.

Comment: Thanks, the dist folder is at the same level as bower_components and node_modules. It's created by gulp. But... _references.js also includes the .js files in dist and .tmp, so that kind of sucks. You're right about the 'black box' magic. Except the magic isn't really working so far.

Comment: Well the "magic" is working.  "exclude" does NOT hide folders from the solution explorer.   The magic I was talking about it how VS hides folders from the solution explorer.  AFAIK there is no way in VS 2015 to say "hide this folder so it doesn't show up in the solution explorer".  VS does that for certain folders (like node_packages) but it is just "magic".  There is no configuration setting to control it or disable it.  For example the reverse is also true.  Say you wanted to SEE "node_dependencies" folder in VS.  You can't.  It is magic and the magic says it is not visible.

Comment: @Elger, I can tell you that if you turn off auto updating for your _references.js, and go in a manually remove the framework entries (all the code you are not providing), it will be a lot better. In fact if you don't do this you probably doom your intellisense.

Answer (score 5):

As of Asp.Net 5 **beta-8** and complementary tooling update to Visual Studio 2015, you are now able to exclude/hide folders from being displayed in solution explorer. More information about this, and other changes are outlined in the [announcement post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx). To hide a file or folder, right-click to bring up a context menu and select `Hide from solution explorer`. This creates an entry in the `.xproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DnxInvisibleContent Include="myhiddenfile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note also that there has been a change to where bower packages are installed by default. Previously, the Asp.Net 5 templates in Visual Studio would install bower packages to a folder called `bower_components`, a practice familiar to web developers who do not use Visual Studio. However, apparently due to developer confusion, this has been changed to `wwwroot/lib`. This can be changed by editing the `bowerrc` file.  As such, the `bower_components` folder does not exist in the new beta-8 templates. Please see [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx) by Scott Hanselman for more information.

Comment: It seems that after you hide the folder the search functionality still "sees" these files, though it should not in my mind. Is there a better way with the RC1 now that you can completely exclude the folder from your project? E.g. I use gulp to create bundles and I don't want them neither in source control, nor in Visual Studio...

Answer (score 3):

It may not be ideal, but I was able to hide a folder from the solution explorer in an Asp.net 5 project by marking the folder as hidden in the windows explorer properties dialog. I had the .idea folder used by WebStorm showing up so it being hidden was not too big a deal. WebStorm doesn't mind.

It seems like the folder will not be hidden if it is already in the solution explorer. Mark it and it's contents hidden and move it temporarily out of the project folder. Make sure it disappears from the solution explorer before moving it back. It should not show back up. A restart of Visual Studio may also work, I didn't test that.

Comment: This is a good solution. And you only need to hide the folder, not the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Rightly or wrongly, here's what I did to get `bower_components` and `.sass-cache` out of the way. In my case, `node_modules` was already excluded from my project somehow, even though it's at the same level with `gruntfile.js`. I still don't understand why it is treated differently. Anyone know?

First, I set my location like this in the `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
  "directory": "../../artifacts/bower_components"
}
```

Then I adjusted my paths as necessary in my `gruntfile.js`

Also, To get the `sass-cache` folder out of the way, since I was using `grunt-contrib-compass`, I configured my compass task with this option:

```
  cacheDir: '../../artifacts/.sass-cache',
```

There are other ways to do this if you are using other sass / compass tools.

**RESULT:**

- I can now search my entire project for text and not get hits in my libraries.
- `bower_components` and `.sass-cache` are out of reach of source control.

Comment: That's indeed a solution, moving bower_components out of your project. I use GIT for source control so I can easily exclude those folders in the .gitignore file, just would've been nice if you can exclude folders with vs2015 so I don't have to restructure my projects.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Visual Studio you just need to right-click the folder/file and chose "Hide from Solution Explorer".

That will change the "xproj" this way:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>
```